How to calculate distance with telemetry data
I have telemetry data with a large number of detections for each individual (ID) at several stations. I want to calculate the total distance travelled by each ID in my study.
Each station is associated with its coordinates (Longitude and Latitude), which I convert to UTM data.
I have created a data that looks like mine, with the same data type (data_detections).
library(lubridate) # ymd_hms()
library(sp)
#generate a random data
generate_random_datetime <- function(start_date, end_date, n) {
  seq(start_date, end_date, by = "min")[sample(1:(as.integer(difftime(end_date, start_date, units = "mins")) + 1), n)]
}
set.seed(123)  
n <- 100  

data_detections <- data.frame(
  Date.and.Time..UTC. = generate_random_datetime(ymd_hms("2024-01-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2024-01-20 23:59:59"), n),
  Receiver = sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE),
  Latitude = runif(n, 52.0, 53.0),
  Longitude = runif(n, 3.0, 4.0) ,
  ID = as.character(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE))
)


I calculated my total distances like that, but the values are not correct when i compare it with my "real" values
#convert to UTM
coord <- SpatialPoints(data_detections[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")], 
                       proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
coord.t <- spTransform(coord, CRS("+proj=utm +datum=WGS84 +zone=43"))
data_detections[, c("Longitude_UTM", "Latitude_UTM")] <- coordinates(coord.t)

head(data_detections)

#caclulate the total distance

total_distance <- function(data) {
  coords <- as.matrix(data[, c("Longitude_UTM", "Latitude_UTM")])
  distances <- sqrt(rowSums((coords[-1, ] - coords[-nrow(coords), ])^2))
  distance <- sum(distances, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(data.frame(distance = distance))
}


total_distances <- data_detections %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  group_modify(~ total_distance(.x))

print(total_distances)


In what region those points should be? Coordinates in example point to Europe and suitable UTM zone would be 31. But zone in example is 43, valid Longitude range for this one is 72 .. 78 and that zone crosses India.

these coords are not mine, I work on Corsica data (island between France and Italy), so I used crs = 4326 with espg 32632 (I am not sure if it is correctly written)

You'll likely want to approach this in sf rather than sp.

If you just need to add up distances between grouped and ordered(*) geographic coordinates, one option is to use geosphere::distGeo(), if you pass it a single 2 column data.frame or matrix, it returns a vector of sequential distances between points on an ellipsoid (default is WGS84), in meters.
* - in your example data you have created a random timestamp sequence, without sorting it first, it would simulate a random point order in your telemetry data, i.e. random distances with random sums.
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(geosphere)

dist_geosphere <- 
  data_detections |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  arrange(Date.and.Time..UTC., .by_group = TRUE) |> 
  mutate(dist_geo  = distGeo(pick(c("Longitude", "Latitude")))) |> 
  summarise(dist_sum_m = sum(dist_geo, na.rm = TRUE))

dist_geosphere
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    ID    dist_sum_m
#>    <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 1        361722.
#>  2 10       556821.
#>  3 2        347572.
#>  4 3        293461.
#>  5 4        470681.
#>  6 5        303046.
#>  7 6        333351.
#>  8 7        556807.
#>  9 8        716994.
#> 10 9        408434.

Example data:
#generate a random data
generate_random_datetime <- function(start_date, end_date, n) {
  seq(start_date, end_date, by = "min")[sample(1:(as.integer(difftime(end_date, start_date, units = "mins")) + 1), n)]
}
set.seed(123)  
n <- 100  

data_detections <- data.frame(
  Date.and.Time..UTC. = generate_random_datetime(ymd_hms("2024-01-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2024-01-20 23:59:59"), n),
  Receiver = sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE),
  Latitude = runif(n, 52.0, 53.0),
  Longitude = runif(n, 3.0, 4.0) ,
  ID = as.character(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE))
)

